# Query child objects through parent model - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, model-inheritance

Is it possible to query all child objects through parent model and eventually get the subclass of every element in the queryset.

**models.py**

```
class employee(models.model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
class teacher(employee):
    school=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    district=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subject=models.CharField(max_length=30)
class doctor(employee):
    hospital=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    specialty=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

If I make a query to get all employees

```
queryset = employee.objects.all()
```

How to get every employee's subclass without making queries for subclasses.

Is the subclass repesented with a field in the parent model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to fetch the data of the `teacher` and/or `doctor` in the same query, so:

```
queryset = employee.objects.select_related('doctor', 'teacher')
```

and then try to access the attribute if that is a subclass:

```
for item in queryset:
    try:
        doctor_details = item.doctor
    except AttributeError:
        pass  # not a doctor
```

This is essentially what the [**`django-polymorphic`** package <sup>[PyPI]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/django-polymorphic/)
does internally.